# How to loop the error trap back to the original question

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a menu option of 5 things. If the user enters a number not between 1 and 5 my program reasks for the number but even if the user puts in a number that works the program still ends.

```
print("   ")
print("pick a menu option between 1-5")
print("   ")
print("   ")
print("1 - Enter RLE")
print("2 - Display ASCII art")
print("3 - covert ASCII art option")
print("4 - convert RLE option")
print("5 - Quit")
print("   ")
print("   ")
print("   ")

user=0

user=int(input('select a number between 1 and 5'))


    if user == 1:
        print("hi")

    elif user == 2:

        user = input('select a file with an ASCII art image')
        f = open(user, 'r')
        if f.mode == 'r':
            showart = f.read()
            print(showart)
    # asking user for file
    #showing the file
    #file name LogoArt.txt

    elif user == 3:
        print("hi")

    elif user == 4:
        print("hi")

    elif user == 5:
        print('goodbye')
        import sys
        sys.exit()
    #exits the program



    else:
        user=int(input("select a number between 1 and 5"))
```

i expect the output of else to be able to reask the original question

Comment: There is the "while"-loop, especially "while True" for this.

Comment: You just need to add a loop. Even a "while True:" would work for this case.  But for future reference, it's a good idea to use more descriptive variables than "user."  EDIT: "error-handling" is not really a good tag for this question, by the way.

Comment: Can you rewrite the code in the answer text to show me as i am useless at python?

Comment: Answer coming right up. Gonna take a bit though. And it's alright. We all start somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot i appreciateyour help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ask (user) :

    if user == 1:
        print("hi")

    elif user == 2:

        user = input('select a file with an ASCII art image ')
        f = open(user, 'r')
        if f.mode == 'r':
            showart = f.read()
            print(showart)

    elif user == 3:
        print("hi")

    elif user == 4:
        print("hi")

    elif user == 5:
        print('goodbye')
        import sys
        sys.exit()


while (True) :


    print("   ")
    print("pick a menu option between 1-5 ")
    print("   ")
    print("   ")
    print("1 - Enter RLE ")
    print("2 - Display ASCII art ")
    print("3 - covert ASCII art option ")
    print("4 - convert RLE option ")
    print("5 - Quit ")
    print("   ")
    print("   ")
    print("   ")

    user=int(input("Select an integer between 1 and 5 : "))

    if (user<5 and user > 1) :
        ask(user)
    else:
        user=int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5 : "))
        while (user > 5 or user < 1) :
            user=int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5 : "))

        ask (user)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The problem with the while true is that none of the menu options work

Comment: included the output

Comment: I tried it again, the menu only works if you get the riight number first time.

Comment: If you use this answer, might wanna throw some spaces at the end of that input() call. Makes it way easier to tell what the input is by looking at the screen.

Comment: Right number first time ?

Comment: If you type in a wrong number, it simply asks for the number again.  But then, it does nothing with that input, and asks for it a third time, and that's the one that is used.  One fix could be to move your first input out of the "while" loop. Another, could be to have it pass or print an error report in your "else" block.

Comment: Editing the answer likewise

Comment: @Amartya Gaur the error trap works with numbers however if you enter a letter the program crashes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could use input() instead of int(input())

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice, simple, and loop-free answer with function definition and even a little recursion in there for you.  Really good things to learn if you're new to python or programming in general. Best of luck to you. And feel free to ask any questions about how it works.

```
def Menu():
#Put all your option prints here. 
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    Option = int(input("Pick an option between 1 and 5.  ")
    print(" ")
    if Option == 1:
        pass #Replace each "pass" with what you want that Option to do. 
        Menu()
    elif Option == 2:
        pass
        Menu()
    elif Option == 3:
        pass
        Menu()
    elif Option == 4:
        pass
        Menu()
    elif Option == 5;
        import sys
        sys.exit()
    else:
        Menu()
Menu()
```

Comment: Can I ask which print?